# Google Apps Directory Sync refusing to use SHA and MD5 hashes?

Tags: google-apps

So I have been trying to get Google Apps Directory Sync to work for a few days now and it seems the only way I can make Google sync is with SHA1, then reconfiguring my LDAP Server to run plaintext passwords and manually hashing and updating passwords with a {SHA1} marker instead of {SHA}.

To me it seems like an inability to keep to standards, from either OpenLDAP or Google, so my question is:
Is this really just an inconsistency in hash standards, or is there actually a way to make this work and if there is a way to make this work, how do I do it?

I am at my wits end here, the Google software for this is really super terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the answer to this question is, it will work, but only if the hash scheme is upper-case, like so: {MD5] and {SHA}.
So the solution is to either use an LDAP browser or built a custom password changing program.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Directory Sync (GADS) only supports SHA1, MD5, Base64 and plaintext passwords as detailed [here](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en/us/support/enterprise/static/gapps/docs/admin/en/gads/admin/gads_admin.pdf#page=85). AFAIK, you will need to change your passwords from SHA(0) > SHA1 as GADS will not be able to resolve the hash otherwise. To test this, you can use one test account and a [hash generator](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html) to confirm it's being synced correctly.

EDIT:

GADS was [updated recently](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1263028?hl=en). Did the update change the behavior at all?

Comment: The thing is, that is what I am already doing, if I copy the SHA hash and uppercase the {sha} to {SHA} and then reinput it is plaintext, Google will sync flawlessly.
For reference the password also works once synced.

Comment: This sounds like the expected behavior to me. You can double check this with the Google for Work Support team to be sure though. I suspect you're going to need to update all the passwords to fit the format that GADS expects. The other alternative would be to implement an SSO solution that supports {sha} as {SHA}.

Comment: Yeah, I just find it rather silly that something like case sensitivity is what breaks the sync, especially seeing as the whole {sha} thing seems to be default OpenLDAP behaviour. But as I described in the solution, I just ended up altering the hash scheme to uppercase and it all seems to work just fine now.

Comment: Edited my first post as an update for GADS was released.